# asp error: Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to make an asp.net website.

I have created a masterpage using the following format:

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="masterPage.master" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH1" runat="server">

<HTML>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
</asp>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH2" runat="server">


</asp>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH3" runat="server">

    </body>

</HTML>

</asp>
```

Where the content form the individual pages will be stored in

```
ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH2"
```

and the content in the placeholders

```
ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH1"
ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH3"
```

will be universal content for all pages sourced from the master page.

I have then made the following page, which is supposed to be my homepage, and saved it as home.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH1" runat="server">
</asp>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH2" runat="server">

    INDIVIDUAL PAGE CONTENT

</asp>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="CPH3" runat="server">

</asp>
```

I think this is done correctly, although I am not sure as I have not been able to find any clear tutorial on what I need to do.

I have uploaded this to the server and loaded the following web address:

> www.'mydomain'.co.uk/home.aspx

But I get the following error:

> Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested >master page that references a master page.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or how to fix it. If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong, or point me to some clear instructions on what I need to do that would be very helpful, including how to configure my default page correctly to point to my homepge

Comment: Generally, your top level master page should contain the basic structure of the site, such as the `head` and `html` elements. And you should definitely not name your controls like 'CPH1` and `CPH2`. A better name should be semantic, it should describe the content that should go in it. Like `SidebarCPH` or `MainBodyCPH`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end your `<asp:` controls tags with fully corresponding closing tags.  Unless this is a syntax that I'm unaware of, you can't use `</asp>`.

So change `</asp>` to `</asp:Content>`.

<strike>However, the main issue is that you're trying to place mark-up outside of the `<asp:Content>` controls.  That is not allowed when the `.aspx` page is using a master page.</strike>

[Ignore the above part, I wasn't reading your code correctly - all your mark-up **is** inside the `<asp:Content>` controls.]

However, what I would say is that it is your masterpage that would normally have all the `<html><head><body>` tags, with `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` controls placed in appropriate locations with appropriate names.  It is unusual to have those tags within the child page.